# Can an exception inside a whenComplete() affect the thread it spun off from?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, future, completable-future

I was under the impression that anything you put in `whenComplete`, happens on a thread totally separate from the thread that spawned it. But we had an incident today where, looking at our logs, it seems as though an exception thrown from within the `whenComplete` bubbled up as if the exception were thrown in a regular chain (*e.g.* `thenApply`, `thenCompose`, etc.), and got caught by an `exceptionally` (in the original chain).

Is that possible? How?

I'm hoping the answer is No, that's not possible, and there's something weird going on / we're misreading our logs or logic.

Comment: If the `CompletableFuture` that you invoked `whenComplete` on is already completed, the `BiConsumer` will be executed inline, ie. the thread calling `whenComplete`. However, any exceptions thrown there will be caught and used to complete the returned `CompletableFuture`. What do you mean by "bubbled up"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Javadoc for CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenComplete(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) says, "...this method is not designed to translate completion outcomes, so *the supplied `action` should not throw an exception.*" But then it tells you what to expect if the `action` *does* throw an exception...

> it seems as though an exception thrown from within the whenComplete bubbled up as if the exception were thrown in a regular chain.

...The Javadoc says, "if this stage completed normally but the supplied action throws an exception, then the returned stage completes exceptionally with the supplied action's exception."

That sounds like the behavior you are seeing.

---

Response to comment:

> But if task B throwing an exception causes task A (upon completing normally) to throw task B's exception, then doesn't that mean task A has to wait on task B?

No. There's no waiting. A `CompletableFuture` can be completed in either of two ways: It can be completed *normally* (e.g., as if by [`complete(T value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#complete(T))), or it can be completed *exceptionally* (as if by [`completeExceptionally(Throwable ex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completeExceptionally(java.lang.Throwable))). In the "exceptionally" case, a reference to the `Throwable ex` object will be stored in the future object.

Some time later, when some other thread eventually calls [`future.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get()) it will return the stored `value` if the the future was normally completed, but if the future was exceptionally completed, then the get() call will `throw new ExecutionException(ex)` where `ex` was the original `Throwable` object that was stored in the future.

So really, there's *two* exceptions thrown; One to report whatever the original bad thing was that happened *when* it happened, and then another that is *deferred* until some other thread calls `future.get()`. In your example, the "bad thing" happened when some pool thread performed the `action` that you supplied to `whenComplete(...,action)`.

Comment: Thanks! It was right in the Javadoc, of course. I have a question though. I thought the whole point of `whenComplete` was so that you don't hold up task A waiting for task B. But if task B throwing an exception causes task A (upon completing normally) to throw task B's exception, then doesn't that mean task A has to wait on task B? To see if it throws an exception?

Comment: @AndrewCheong, No. See what I added to my answer, above.

Comment: Thanks again! I was a little uncareful with my words, although maybe you understood regardless. I meant: I thought the point of `whenComplete` was that I could spawn a totally unrelated task after Task A completed, but let Task A be "gotten" (_e.g._ return its response to the caller) without needing to know how Task B completed. If we're on the same page, then is your answer perhaps saying that it's a race condition? _e.g._ If some other thread eventually calls `future.get()` _before_ Task B throws an exception, then it will get the normally completed Task A; but if _after_, then it throws?

Comment: @AndrewCheong, There's no race condition. `future.get()` always waits for the `future` to be completed before it either returns or throws. I don't know for sure what really is happening in your code because you only tried to describe it in words—you haven't showed any of it. But, it sounds like you are building a _chain_ of `CompletableFuture` objects. If you are unsure of how the "chaining" works, then that would be a good topic for a new StackOverflow question.