# How does whenComplete() work in a chain of CompletionStages?

Tags: java, exception, completable-future, java-threads

I thought I understood `whenComplete` but I'm not sure now. This question originated [in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73130069/can-an-exception-inside-a-whencomplete-affect-the-thread-it-spun-off-from/73130785?noredirect=1#comment129172512_73130785).

The way we work with futures in my company is by chaining them:

```
CompletionStage<Foo> getFoo() {
  // ...
  return barService.getBar()
      .thenCompose(bar -> {
        CompletionStage<Baz> baz = bazService.getBaz(bar);
        // ...
        return qux;
      })
      .thenApply(qux -> {
        CompletionStage<Quux> quux = quuxService.getQuux(qux);
        // ...
        return foo;
      });
}
```

<sup>*qux* and *quux* are apparently the [metasyntactic variables](https://github.com/substack/metasyntactic-variables) that follow *foo*, *bar*, and *baz*.</sup>

Now let's say I wanted to send a confirmation email when `foo` has been gotten. I don't need the sending of this confirmation email to hold up the response to whatever client called `getFoo`. We use `whenComplete` for these scenarios:

```
CompletionStage<Foo> getFoo() {
  // ...
  return barService.getBar()
      .thenCompose(bar -> {
        CompletionStage<Baz> baz = bazService.getBaz(bar);
        // ...
        return qux;
      })
      .thenApply(qux -> {
        CompletionStage<Quux> quux = quuxService.getQuux(qux);
        // ...
        return foo;
      })                                     _
      .whenComplete((foo, ex) -> {.           |
          if (ex == null) {                   |
            emailService.sendEmail(foo);      | (NEW)
          }                                   |
      });                                    _|
}
```

Now I thought the action in `whenComplete` happened in a separate thread completely independently of the thread it originated from. In other words, I thought as soon as `foo` was found, it'd be on its way to the caller, no matter what happened inside the `whenComplete`. But in reality, when the email service had a problem and threw an exception, **the exception propagated all they way up, *i.e.* `getFoo` threw an exception,** even though `foo` was found succesfully.

I was pointed to [the Javadoc for `whenComplete`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenComplete(java.util.function.BiConsumer)), which indeed says:

> Unlike method handle, this method is not designed to translate completion outcomes, so the supplied action should not throw an exception. However, if it does, the following rules apply: if this stage completed normally but the supplied action throws an exception, then the returned stage completes exceptionally with the supplied action's exception. Or, if this stage completed exceptionally and the supplied action throws an exception, then the returned stage completes exceptionally with this stage's exception.

So here's where I'm confused:

I thought the whole point of `whenComplete` was to allow the originating thread to continue on its way without having to wait for the action in `whenComplete`. If whether or not the chain will complete normally depends on the `whenComplete` action though, doesn't that mean the chain always has to wait to see how `whenComplete` completes? How is `whenComplete` helping at all, if that's true?

I'm sure that I'm thinking of something wrong / misunderstanding how futures work, but I don't know what.

Comment: [In which thread do CompletableFuture's completion handlers execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46060438/in-which-thread-do-completablefutures-completion-handlers-execute)

Comment: I'm not seeing the source of the confusion. 'whenComplete' means 'when the previous stage has completed, either normally or exceptionally, call this with the results'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.whenComplete` is similar to a `finally` block. It's useful when you want to do something even if the previous stage has failed. For example, log an exception or clean up some resources without stopping the propagation of the failure.

In your case, it seems that you want to send an email only when there are no failures. You could rewrite it as:

```
.thenAccept(emailService::sendEmail);
```

In this case if `sendEmail` returns void, `.thenAccept` will return when the method completes. But if `sendEmail` returns a `CompletionStage<Void>`, `thenAccept` will continue without waiting for the result (and failure or successes will be ignored).

If you want to have control over the thread executors, you can use the `.then*Async` methods instead of the regular ones. Otherwise, the pipeline will run everything in the same thread (if possible, it's not always the case).

Comment: Okay, I think I'm starting to understand. And I'm pretty I understand the `thenAccept`. But how do I make it so that `foo` being returned and the email being sent run in parallel? (Rather than having to wait for the email thread to complete—because that's what `thenAccept` will do, right?) That was the reason I was using `whenComplete` but maybe it wasn't the right tool.

Comment: you could run `sendEmail` using `runAsync`: `.thenAccept( foo -> CompletableFuture.runAsync( () -> emailService.sendEmail(foo) ))`

Comment: I see. I guess I looked at `whenComplete` as the chainable way to do that. I don't think even `thenAcceptAsync` does the same as what you've provided, right?

Comment: They all follow the same concept. If you want to run things in parallel, you have to create a new completion stage or start a new thread